# Complexe sql query within where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a DB over 1M entries and i need to perform a query in mysql.
I have 2 colonn with 2 numbers. One is a long entreprise number and the other short entreprise number. Both numbers are related. 
For instance : a company will have a short number of 112233445 and long number of 11223344566777. 
What i need to do is to select all lines where short number is different of the beginning of long number. Can you help me ?

Comment: Column data types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LIKE`:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE long_num NOT LIKE CONCAT(short_num, '%')
```

If you *also* want to restrict results to long numbers which don't have 14 characters, then you can add a second condition to the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE long_num NOT LIKE CONCAT(short_num, '%') AND
      CHAR_LENGTH(long_num) <> 14
```

Comment: `I have 2 colonn with 2 numbers.` ... do you interpret this differently?

Comment: just an other question as you seems expert : how can i have results where long_number doesn't have 14 caracters ?